# Why can't I change data value in a method in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```html
<script lang="ts">
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      continued: false,
      played: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    some(){
      this.played == true
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

If i Try to Change `played` on 14th Line it Gives me:

> Property 'played' does not exist on type '{ some: () => void; }'

How can I fix this one?

Comment: oops, im trying to do `this.played == true` btw

Comment: The given error is about types (Typescript). If you don't care about it, you can omit `lang="ts"`.

Comment: okay, lemme try

Comment: So, does it work without the TS errors?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Just `this.played = true` if wanna change the played value.